# PDFBox issue while creating a new page dynamically

Tags: java, pdfbox

Consider a SQL query whose result will be written into the pdf.

I can write the contents (retrieved from the query) in the pdf successfully but it truncates the content if it crosses the maximum limit of one page. It means, only one page gets created.

While writing into the pdf (via PDFBox), how to know that we have reached the end of a page, so that we can trigger `doc.addPage(page);` once we know dynamically that we have reached to the end point of the page.

Here is the below code:

```
public PDDocument processPdf(Class1 objectClass1) {
    String text;
    int count;
    //New Document is created
    PDDocument doc = new PDDocument();
    List<Class1Questions> objectClass1Questions;
    Class2 objectClass2;
    try {
        float fontSize = 12;
        float margin = 72;
        float leading = 1.5f * fontSize;
        PDFont font = PDType1Font.HELVETICA;
        PDPage page = new PDPage();
        page.setMediaBox(PDRectangle.A4);
        PDRectangle pageSize = page.getMediaBox();
        float startX = pageSize.getLowerLeftX() + margin;
        float startY = pageSize.getUpperRightY() - margin;
        //First page is added
        doc.addPage(page);
        List<String> lines;
        PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(doc, page);
        contentStream.setFont(font, fontSize);
        contentStream.beginText();
        //The resultset gets collected and written in PDF.
        text = objectClass1.getClass1Name();
        lines = spacing(text, margin, font, pageSize);
        contentStream.newLineAtOffset(startX, startY);
        contentStream.showText("Class1: ");
        for (String line : lines) {
            contentStream.showText(line);
            contentStream.newLineAtOffset(0, -leading);
        }
        List<Class1Version> versionList = objectClass1.getClass1Versions();
        for (Class1Version version : versionList) {

            String versionNum = Long.toString(version.getClass1VersionNumber());
            contentStream.showText("Version: " + versionNum);

            contentStream.newLineAtOffset(0, -leading);
            objectClass1Questions = version.getClass1Questions();
            count = 0;
            for (Class1Questions objectClass1Question : objectClass1Questions) {
                count++;
                objectClass2 = objectClass1Question.getQuestion();
                String question = objectClass2.getQuestionDesc();
                lines = spacing(question, margin, font, pageSize);
                contentStream.showText("Q" + count + ": ");
                for (String line : lines) {
                    contentStream.showText(line);
                    contentStream.newLineAtOffset(0, -leading);
                }
                contentStream.newLineAtOffset(0, -leading);
            }
        }
        contentStream.endText();
        contentStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return doc;
    }

    public List<String> spacing (String text, float margin, PDFont font, PDRectangle pageSize) throws IOException {
    int lastSpace = -1;
    List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
    float fontSize = 25;
    float width = pageSize.getWidth() - 2*margin;

    while (text.length() > 0)
    {
        int spaceIndex = text.indexOf(' ', lastSpace + 1);
        if (spaceIndex < 0)
            spaceIndex = text.length();
        String subString = text.substring(0, spaceIndex);
        float size = fontSize * font.getStringWidth(subString) / 1000;
        System.out.printf("'%s' - %f of %f\n", subString, size, width);
        if (size > width)
        {
            if (lastSpace < 0)
                lastSpace = spaceIndex;
            subString = text.substring(0, lastSpace);
            lines.add(subString);
            text = text.substring(lastSpace).trim();
            System.out.printf("'%s' is line\n", subString);
            lastSpace = -1;
        }
        else if (spaceIndex == text.length())
        {
            lines.add(text);
            System.out.printf("'%s' is line\n", text);
            text = "";
        }
        else
        {
            lastSpace = spaceIndex;
        }
    }
    return lines;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand why this is a question; you are able to write contents. Thus you put them at Y-positions. Because the top of a page is the height, it means that the nearer you get to the bottom, the smaller your y value has become; and if it is <0 then you no longer see it. The only explanation I can come up with is that you started with y= 0 and didn't notice that on your page all was in reverse.

Comment: Updated the post with my existing code.

Comment: You will have to introduce a variable in which you note the current **y** coordinate, setting it to `startY` when you do `contentStream.newLineAtOffset(startX, startY)`, decreasing it by `leading` each time you do `contentStream.newLineAtOffset(0, -leading)`, and checking in these situations, too, whether that variable value is too small (most like less than `margin`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare a totalHeight variable, set it to margin height;

```
float totalHeight = margin;
```

Get font height like below:

```
float fontHeight = font.getFontDescriptor().getFontBoundingBox()
            .getHeight()
            / 1000 * fontSize;
```

But it will not return the exact height, you can play with it to get better results. 
Then get a4 page size:

```
float a4Height= PDRectangle.A4.getHeight();
```

Everytime you enter a new line increase total height and check if it is exceeding the a4Height considering the margin height

```
totalHeight += fontHeight;
if(totalHeight+margin>=a4Height){
    page = new PDPage();
    doc.addPage(page);
    totalHeight = margin;
}
```

Comment: You need to reset your totalHeight variable.

Comment: @Pratim Singha, please press the checkmark if the answer solved your problem, or tell what happened if it didn't.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried to take the solution given by @AhmetRasitBekar and the solution mentioned in the comment by @mkl.

1. Introduce a variable in which you note the current y coordinate,
   setting it to startY. Consider the variable as `yCordinate`.
2. Calculated the font height

   `float fontHeight = font.getFontDescriptor().getFontBoundingBox().getHeight() / 1000 * fontSize;`
3. Each time the text contents are written into the pdf file, the variable
   `yCordinate` will be decreased by `fontHeight`.

   `contentStream.showText(line);
   yCordinate -= fontHeight;`
4. Each time a new line has been added, the `yCordinate` is decreased by
   `leading`

`contentStream.newLineAtOffset(0, -leading);
yCordinate -= leading;`

5. Each time the `yCordinate` is accessed and changed, a conditional
   statement is written to check whether the `yCordinate <= 10`. If
   yes, then the below code.

> ```
> if(yCordinate <= 10){
>      page = new PDPage();  //new page created
>      page.setMediaBox(PDRectangle.A4);
>      pageSize = page.getMediaBox();
>      startX = pageSize.getLowerLeftX() + margin;  //Calculate the X and Y cordinate
>      startY = pageSize.getUpperRightY() - margin;
>      doc.addPage(page);  //Add the page to the PDDocument
>      yCordinate = startY;   //Reset the yCordinate with the new Y cordinate
>      contentStream.endText();  //End and Close the previous contentStream
>      contentStream.close();
>      contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(doc, page);  //Create a new contentStream and use it further
>      contentStream.setFont(font, fontSize);
>      contentStream.beginText();
>      contentStream.newLineAtOffset(startX, startY);
>  }
> ```

This will dynamically create pages in the pdf if the content exceeds the PDF page limit.